# Powershell - working with dates

Tags: powershell

I have a pclist.csv file like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
| Name | LastLogonTimestamp | Some Other Data |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2342 | 23/05/2012         | Blah Blah Blah  |
-----------------------------------------------
| 3433 |                    | Yada Yada Yada  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, some of the LastLogonTimestamp cells don't contain any data and some do.

I'm trying to examine this .csv using a powershell function like this:

```
$assets = import-csv pclist.csv

Function ActiveDesktop
{
foreach ($asset in $assets)
    {
    if ($asset.'LastLogonTimestamp' -le {get-date.adddays(-90) -format "ddMMyyyy"})
        {write-host $asset.Name, $asset."LastLogonTimestamp"}
    }
}
```

I want to see which PCs are inactive, but running the query doesn't return anything. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get all records with empty `LastLogonTimestamp` or older then 90 days:

```
.\Import-Csv pclist.csv | `
    ? { 
        $_.LastLogonTimestamp -eq "" -or `
        [DateTime]::Parse( $_.LastLogonTimestamp) -le [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-90)
    }
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. Just I think you accidentally left a leading space before the second $_.LastLogonTimestamp though. After removing that it worked as expected :-)